# Change Window Title Depending On Content Editable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I would like it so that a variable (let's say "title")is set to the window title, then, if you set the content to editable, the window will be called "Edit On" and when you turn it off it sets the window title to the variable "title". Although I still don't really understand JavaScript to well so it would be helpful if somebody could write the line of code or help me out. Here is the code that I am currently using.

```
document.body.contentEditable = document.body.contentEditable == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true'; 
document.designMode=document.designMode == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
document.close;
```

Comment: You mean you have a e.g. HTML `<div>` element on screen which's contentEditable property is set to true and as soon as someone is changing it's content the window title should be changed? I'm not sure what you mean by turning contentEditable on or off.

Comment: Try adding “javascript:” to the the front of the code and run it as a bookmarklet, I would like it to rename the tab to show if the whole page is editable or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but if you set contentEditable to true for the whole body there's no coming back. How would a user go about leaving 'edit mode'?

What you can do however is adding an empty HTML `<div>` element to the DOM, make it almost the whole size of the browser window and add something like a 'ready' button.

There are two helpful event listeners for your use case:

**onfocus:** this will fire as soon as the user clicks somewhere inside the div/typing anything in there. If it gets fired change the document title.

**onblur:** this will fire as soon as the user clicks somewhere outside the div. If it gets fired reset the document title to it's default.

Additionally you might add a **click** listener to the ready button to leave edit mode and change the document title as well.

Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:90%;background-color:rgb(240,240,240)" contentEditable=true>
</div>
<button id="readyButton">Ready</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDocumentTitle = "My Title";
document.title = myDocumentTitle;
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.onfocus = function() {
  document.title = "Edit On";
}
myDiv.onblur = function() {
  document.title = myDocumentTitle;
}
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.onclick = function() {
  document.title = myDocumentTitle;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would set it to false. I am trying to do document.title = example when the content is set to editable, keep in mind, this is going to be run as an bookmarklet.

Comment: I think I’ll just keep the bookmarklet on my website how it is, thank you for the help though.